# If statement doesn't give cout after the first attempt

Tags: c++

Why does the if statement not produce the cout after the first attempt, not sure what is happening here, how can i get this loop to work?

```
srand(time(0) );
int random = rand();
int pswd = (random);

std::cout << pswd << endl;

int pswdattempt;
std::cin >> pswdattempt;


while (pswdattempt != pswd) {
    if (pswdattempt == pswd) {
        std::cout << "Access Granted" << endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cin >> pswdattempt;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you close the `while` in the full script, and that this is within a function otherwise srand is unlikely to work.

notice if input is correct on first input (before the loop) it will be explicitly excluded by `while (pswdattempt != pswd)`.

likewise, if the correct integer is given at the prompt in the loop, then the loop will not restart, so the `if (pswdattempt == pswd)` will still not be reached.

essentially you need a flow that prompts for input, then tries the condition, returning to the prompt if unmet, else exiting the loop to continue granting access or dispensing chocolate if met correctly.

(edit) if cout still produces nothing, i'm a little out of depth here, but i see you havn't set `use namespace std;` globally so perhaps each `endl;` should be `std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.  First is that the `rand()` function generates a pseudo random number between 0 and some fairly large number, typically at least 32K.  This means that you might be sitting there for a while waiting to guess the right number.  For testing purposes, try generating a number between 0 and 10.  Then, break out of the `while` loop on a correct guess:

```
srand(time(0) );
int random = rand() % 10;
int pswd = (random);

std::cout << pswd << endl;

int pswdattempt;

do {
    std::cout << "Please enter a password";
    std::cin >> pswdattempt;

    if (pswdattempt == pswd) {
        std::cout << "Access Granted" << endl;
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: The `if` statement true condition will never be executed

Comment: guessing the answer won't be an issue, it is displayed to user at the start